# Monitor server using LCD 5.25 bay screen - How?

Tags: php, monitoring

I'm looking for an lcd display to fit in one 5.25 inch bay... I found a lot of that but I'm looking for a way to change the display using command-line, since no screen will be attached to that computer... When something occur on the computer, it will be displayed on the lcd screen.

I want to monitor cu, hdd health, activity on the server using this lcd, since the server is running under windows, I will use PHP to get information and execute a command line to change the informations on the LCD.

I found MAtrix orbital and nmedia lcd screen but no command line support :(

Any hint how to do something like that, any interresting products?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking you may need to integrate a PLC/LCD in order to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running linux/bsd, you may wish to take a look at lcdproc, doesn't have all the functionality you want but has a few things you haven't mentioned - if you are looking to program yourself, it may be easier tweaking their source code rather than starting from scratch.

FAQ - http://lcdproc.org/faq.php3

Screenshots - http://lcdproc.org/screenshots.php3

Supported Screens - http://lcdproc.org/hardware.php3

Comment: He is running Windows. But similar software exists there as well.

Comment: Oops - I re-read the whole post trying to check OS and still missed it - lesson learned :(

Comment: I think I'm going to switch for centos or something similar :)

Answer (score 2):

[LCDSmartie](http://lcdsmartie.sourceforge.net/) looks quite extensible, I believe it should fit your needs. If so, just grab one of the supported devices.

There is also a standard for USB-connected LCD devices called iMon - originally made for home theater PCs. There is a lot of software out there for it.